# How can I use an app setting in a custom resolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, automapper

I'll try and explain what I want to do. I have a `Server` object, that contains a parameter with a date of when it was last "synced"

```
public class Server
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSyncedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map this to a `ServerSummary` object, which has a `Status` parameter.

```
public class ServerSummary
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

This status will be set by checking to see if the Server has been synced in the last X minutes, with X being stored in my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "SyncOffsetMinutes": "5"
}
```

I have a model class for this:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public int SyncOffsetMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

which is configured in my Startup.cs class:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
}
```

To resolve this `Status` property, I have this in my AutoMapper profile configuration:

```
public class MyAutoMapperProfileConfiguration : Profile
{
    public MyAutoMapperProfileConfiguration()
    {
        CreateMap<Server, ServerSummary>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Status, o => o.ResolveUsing<ServerSyncStatusResolver>());
    }
}
```

In my custom resolver, I'm trying to use DI to inject my AppSettings so that I can use the app setting in my Resolve method:

```
public class ServerSyncStatusResolver : IValueResolver<Server, ServerSummary, string>
{
    private AppSettings _appSettings;

    public ServerSyncStatusResolver(AppSettings appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
    }

    public string Resolve(Server source, ServerSummary destination, string member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.LastSyncedAt.AddMinutes(_appSettings.SyncOffsetMinutes) < DateTime.UtcNow ? "Offline" : "Online";
    }
}
```

But when I actually do my mapping:

```
var servers = _dbContext.Servers.ToList();
var serverSummaries = Mapper.Map<List<Server>, List<ServerSummary>>(servers);
```

I get an error saying

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Is there a way to inject my AppSettings file into the resolver? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you add dependency injection for AppSettings?

Comment: Please, no tags in question title. See [Tagging in Helpcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Seminda I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2492

Comment: Thanks for the link @LucianBargaoanu, but I'm not sure what I need to change in my solution to make it work. Do I need to add something in my Startup class?

Answer (score 1):

**I was very much wrong, see the update below**

You can not use injections at this point, because the resolver instance is created at the time the mapper configuration is initialized.
The only possibility is to put AppSettings as a part of one of the objects to be mapped.

The only thing you can use is a static class and update its members from another places, but this is a very, very, very bad solution. I did not tell you, it's almost illegal =)

**Update by @Lucian Bargaoanu from comments**

You can find answer in documentation [here](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html)

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html